# Error node.js connecting to Postgres: client.query is not a function

Tags: node.js, pg

I guess I am missing something quite obvious. Why cannot I query the db and I am getting this error:

`TypeError: client.query is not a function`

The code is quite simple:

```
const consts = require('./constants');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const process = require('process');
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client } = require("pg")

const command = "login_user"
const pass = "login_user"

const client = connectToDb();

if (command === consts.LOGIN_USER) {
    loginUser(client, pass);
}

async function connectToDb() {
    const dbClient = new Client({});
    await dbClient.connect();
    return dbClient;
}

async function loginUser(client, pass) {
    const query = { text: 'SELECT * FROM users' }
    const res = await client.query(query).rows;
    console.log(res);
    await client.end();
}
```

The credentials for the db are in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem was that the connectToDb() function needs to be called from within an async function.

Here's the code which I got working:

```js
handleInput();

async function handleInput() {
    const client = await connectToDb();
    if (command === consts.LOGIN_USER) {
        await loginUser(client, username, pass);
    }
    await client.end();
}

async function connectToDb() {
    const dbClient = new Client({});
    await dbClient.connect();
    return dbClient;
}

async function loginUser(client, username, pass) {
    // Some operations with db
}
```